# Constructor not recognizing attribute member

Tags: python

I have the following constructor for my `Dbconn` class:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.host     = "localhost"
    self.database = "my_database"
    self.username = "username"
    self.password = "password"

    try:
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect(
            self.host,
            self.username,
            self.password,
            self.database
        )
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    except:
        print "There was an error while connecting to the database"
        self.db.rollback()
```

however, when I execute the program, I get:

```
  File "database.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.db.rollback()
AttributeError: Dbconn instance has no attribute 'db'
```

Any clues why I'm getting that?

Comment: Only catch the exceptions that you know how to handle.  In this case, I don't know what the problem is with your code, but it would be nice to know what the exception is that causes you to enter the `except` clause.

Comment: **edit** -- I do know what the problem is -- I just didn't look close enough.  I still hold by my original statement -- Only handle exceptions that you expect and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `MySQLdb.connect()` fails, `self.db` is not set *at all*. There is no point in rolling back at that point.

Start by setting it to `None`, then test for that in the `except` handler:

```
db = None

def __init__(self):
    self.host     = "localhost"
    self.database = "my_database"
    self.username = "username"
    self.password = "password"

    try:
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect(
            self.host,
            self.username,
            self.password,
            self.database
        )
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    except MySQLdb.Error:
        print "There was an error while connecting to the database"
        if self.db is not None:
            self.db.rollback()
```

I also made the exception handler more specific; blanket `except` handlers are rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing gets assigned to `self.db` if `MySQLdb.connect` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If `MySQLdb.connect` fails, the `db` attribute won't be assigned. Also, what do you want to rollback if a connect to the DB failed?